# prob in starting new activity

Tags: java, android

Please help me 
In my Project when i m starting new activity it is crashing

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.shortnews);
     showNewsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.shortnewslistview);
     ShortNewsListAdapter listAdapter = new ShortNewsListAdapter(this);
     showNewsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
     showNewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
     long arg3) {
    newspostion = position;
    Log.v("status ","tab on position"+position);
       //showProgressDialog(true);
    try {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstTab.this, NewsWebView.class);
     FirstTab.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.v("error","error in starting new activity");
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
  });
     getUrlData(baseUrl);
     }
```

and  i m adding this part in manifiest file also

```
<activity android:name="NewsWebView" android:label="WebView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

this is web view i want to show

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "utf-8";

    WebView wv;

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    wv.loadData("www.gmail.com", mimeType, encoding);

}
```

**Log**

```
10-29 13:10:15.784: VERBOSE/status(203): tab on position0
10-29 13:10:15.784: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=org.nuvus/.NewsWebView }
10-29 13:10:15.814: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(203): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4377c300 has no id.
10-29 13:10:16.764: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Displayed activity org.nuvus/.NewsWebView: 925 ms (total 925 ms)
10-29 13:10:16.794: INFO/AndroidRuntime(203): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(0)
10-29 13:10:16.904: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Process org.nuvus (pid 203) has died.
10-29 13:10:16.924: INFO/WindowManager(53): WIN DEATH: Window{438425d8 org.nuvus/org.nuvus.Main paused=true}
10-29 13:10:16.924: INFO/WindowManager(53): WIN DEATH: Window{438e15c8 org.nuvus/org.nuvus.NewsWebView paused=false}
10-29 13:10:17.064: WARN/UsageStats(53): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in org.nuvus
10-29 13:10:17.144: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 203 uid 10027
10-29 13:13:45.264: DEBUG/dalvikvm(102): GC freed 7488 objects / 406792 bytes in 313ms
10-29 13:10:16.794: INFO/AndroidRuntime(203): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(0)
```

Comment: are u using TabHost in your app

Comment: yes i m using TabHost and there i want if i click on in a tab i m showing a list view and in the listview touch i want to show the webview

Answer (score 0):

the above code is so jumbled. can't understand properly.
You must have to mention the new activity you are trying to open in your Manifest.xml. So first check this that have you mentioned it?

Comment: Edited this (at least a bit) for you, in case you still want to answer it. But keep an eye on the date, it's almost a year old.